# What is being watched by filter.watch?

Tags: web3js, filters

I'm interacting with the blockchain using MetaMask.
Here's my JS code:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter('latest');
    filter.watch(callback)

function callback(error, result){
    console.log(result);
}
```

After I run this code I start to recieve 32 byte hashes (1 hash in 10 - 15 seconds).

```
VM183:5 0x58e2dee05f23f4eed79505c5bf206a9f0a40fa63b7292e0e6e74f7d617cc96c0
VM183:5 0x6e4bde273ade0e8a6f89043e984fa9868f9a5be8f872ebd49886d151575e71c4
VM183:5 0xea0a0d730a6a478adda9d612b4a17451732d3a570ff8d8cd3c19ea0b7808c944
VM183:5 0xa28edff62ecd25fe579f1bd369d215f5587dee6f6be1d69f85d3995f0d7bb0c8
VM183:5 0xe382fc446246e83124205535b915768c16f5d2e1ebb72e9a171da770ec827c89
VM183:5 0x2f246cb4f09e88f05b4f19539d4aac2a4bcfd8294f18899cb5df14cd7941885c
VM183:5 0x1621d5b8eda67208a146b043b3c23f1bc89c918cfec011106c6714f05ccd37bf
...
```

Here's a browser console snapshot:
[image]

What are those? There are not txhashes/blockhashes, because when I put any of them into the search field on https://testnet.etherscan.io I get:

> Unable to locate Transaction entry

Maybe they are signatures of events that fire on the blockchain when the new block is mined. I'm really confused.

From web3 api [docs:](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

> filter.watch(callback): Watches for state changes that fit the filter and calls the callback.

What are state changes in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, these are blockhashes. From web3 api:

> When using the "latest" parameter, it returns the block hash of the last incoming block.